# PigStorage with option tagsource not working

Tags: apache-pig

I am using Pig 0.10. I want to use "filename" later on for some thing.

But when I do:

```
load 'fileName' USING PigStorage(',','-tagsource');
```

I get the message :

```
usage: PigStorage(',', '[options]')
 -noschema   Disable attempting to load data schema from the filesystem.
 -schema     Loads / Stores the schema of the relation using a hidden JSON
             file.
2014-05-10 03:23:22,547 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: could not instantiate 'PigStorage' with arguments '[,, -tagsource]'
```

Any idea why `tagsource` is not getting recognized?